# error Mounting Windows Share with fstab and CIFS

Tags: windows, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to mount permanently a Windows Share through the `fstab` and basically I have added this line to the file:

```
//192.168.0.100/backup$ /home/username/Share/winShare cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,uid=10000 0
```

Basically it seems to work, I see the share and I can create folder or file, but during the boot I see this error:

```
[20.978283] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/724214/cifs-samba-mount-still-attempts-before-network-is-ready-even-with-netdev as it's getting the error because it's trying to mount before the network is ready.

Comment: Please update your post with contents of `systemctl status media-*`. Which Ubuntu version do you have?